# How to handle the Before Close Event in a WPF Browser Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, browser, xbap

I am just starting with a `WPF` Browser application.

I would like to handle the Before Close Event of the browser, so how would i handle that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4cdfa01b-374b-45b9-8d34-fe782ebb28b3/) solution.

In the App.xaml.cs file:

```
 private void Application_Onexit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)

        { 

          //write your code in here!

        }
```

In the App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="(yourclasss)"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup"
             Exit="Application_Onexit"
             ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"
             StartupUri="startup.xaml">
```

So basically the ShutdownMode property needs to be set in order to make it work.

Then add a `event` in app.xaml.cs:

```
public static event EventHandler UnloadPageWorkaround;

public void Application_Onexit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    UnloadPageWorkaround.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Then on the relevant page:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        WPFBrowser.App.UnloadPageWorkaround += new EventHandler(DoMySpecialPageCleanupStuff);
    }

    void DoMySpecialPageCleanupStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do cleanup
    }
```

The only problem with this is, you can't stop the application from exiting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can put your code in Closed/Closing event of main window then..Effect will be same, code-simplier. What did you mean by asking about 'before closing browser'? Web browser or browser control from wpf, located in another window?..Sorry, but when i was answering-i thought that you were talking about webbrowser CONTROL.

Comment: @0x49D1 No, it is a `XBAP` `WPF` Browser Application. So there is no window or WebBrowser Control, only `Pages`. So, i want a similar event like Window_Closing (On a Window) for the browser(something like: Browser_Closing), but it seems there is none...

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your question correctly you can:

- add your BrowserControl tosome Window and handle Window's Closing event.
- or you can try    variations of Unloaded event(this one all
  FrameworkElement objects have).

**Update**
Sorry, just came back..
Example:

```
yourControl.Unloaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                // some code here
                e.Handled = true;
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The first option will not work for me. The second one sound good. Can u maybe post an example?

Comment: No luck. I added a method in there, but nothing happens. This is my code: `this.Unloaded += (s, e) => { CloseTabs(); e.Handled = true; };`
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what CloseTabs() does. Or maybe Unloaded is not firing at all...Try to use debugger and find out problem.

Comment: I just checked. It only fires when u navigate back. Not when i click the close button? Any other idea what i can try next?